# Ok to use RS bearings in a scooter instead of ZZ?

Tags: bearings, kick-scooter

I need to replace the bearings on my (3-year-old daughter's) scooter. The bearings it came with are 608ZZ, where the ZZ indicates a [steel shield](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/76719/can-i-use-zz-steel-seal-ball-bearing-instead-of-rs-rubber-seal). The bearings I'm seeing on amazon when I search for scooter wheels tend to be 608RS (RS = rubber shield).

Should I buy RS (rubber shield) bearings for the scooter?  Why or why not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the RS bearings. As you presumably know, the physical dimensions are identical.

RS means a rubber seal that is in contact with the inner and outer race. To the best of my knowledge, [shielded bearings offer less protection against contamination than rubber seals](https://www.bearingtips.com/difference-bearing-shields-bearing-seals/). The shields don't contact the races. The downside of a full-contact seal is that there is more drag. However, the added friction isn't an issue in your application. I don’t think that ZZ bearings are commonly specified on bicycle applications at all.

I can't say why the scooter was offered with shielded bearings in the first place. If ZZ bearings are cheaper than RS, then that could explain why, but I don't know if that's the case or what the price differential is. One of the stated rationales for metal shields is that they can take higher operating temperatures than rubber seals. However, we are talking about several hundred degrees, and your 3-year old daughter presumably won’t be operating at that temperature.

Comment: Even the tiniest difference in price means savings of $$$$ in mass production.

Comment: +1. My perception is the metal shielded type are both the cheapest and also have the best initial feel/performance (despite suffering more for being left in the yard etc) and so they usually get the nod in mainstream toy/kids applications.

Comment: It is possible to imagine a scenario where metal shields are chosen because there's some other seal in the way first that's part of the larger hub design, such that a contact seal is redundant. There have been bike hubs with no seals or one seal for that reason. But it's probably not the case here.

Comment: Maybe parents try to spin the wheels in the store and if it does not spin freely like a fidget spinner, they are not as eager to buy the scooter :)

Comment: @jpa maybe that comment was made in jest, but it is at least somewhat plausible. Many people would attempt to make at least a cursory assessment of quality, and spinning the wheels is at least a palpable indicator. That said, it could be misleading here.